# How to make Dynamic data capture for Pivot Table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

how would I make this piece of code dynamic so the rows and columns so the code would continue to work even for different data sets.

```
Sheets.Add
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
"Sheet1!R1C1:**R5000C200**", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
"Sheet2!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=6
```

Comment: Make your source data a table (`ListObjeect`) first.

Comment: Or [find the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba). And similarly find that last column.